# My Laptop cannot display. The lead gets power but nothing is displayed on the screen

Tags: laptop-display

Power blacked out when my laptop was on and it cannot display. It does not have battery so i was using direct power. I tried using an external monitor but it displays broken and faint images but on the laptop screen it shows nothing. What can this problem be? How can i fixed it.?

Comment: You will need to provide more information about your laptop - what make/model is it? Maybe provide specs like graphics card, amount of RAM, etc.

Answer (score 1):

My immediate guess is that your video card has failed. If it's not built into the motherboard you can see about replacing just that part. If it is part of the motherboard you'll have to replace the whole motherboard, unfortunately. One thing worth mentioning - if it's a newer laptop check to see if it's still under warranty. If so, you may be able to get this fixed by the manufacturer.

There is another less likely scenario - there was actually a surge and the CFLs (or their related components) have failed for both the external and the laptop monitor. That would at least explain the faint images on the external (the display sounds like it is still working but the backlight isnt). If you want to be thorough test out the external monitor on another device and see how it displays. If you get a bright image like normal then the monitor is fine and it's definitely just the laptop hardware having the problems.

Comment: Another possibility is that the internal power supply has failed and is not providing a needed voltage.